# React with Redux app only works if redux tools installed

Tags: reactjs, redux, firebase-hosting

I have built an app with react and redux. I build the app in the standard way.

```
npm run build --prod
```

The app is then deployed to firebase hosting. I found that the app will not load in Chrome, Firefox, or Safari unless the redux web dev tools are installed. Why is this and how can I stop it?

The app is at ... https://triviatime-e7aa2.web.app/

Comment: An error is triggered when the createStore it is why nothing is displayed :  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at eval (webpack-internal:///321:30)
    at createStore (webpack-internal:///318:56)
    at exports.default (webpack-internal:///1136:45)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///539:31)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:3666)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at bundle.js:63
    at bundle.js:66

Comment: Looks like you're deploying a react application on dev mode, I'm guessing that's why you are getting errors that you need to have redux dev tools installed

Comment: If you are configuring your store in following way, check my answer.

`const store = createStore(
   reducer, 
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
 );`

Comment: What do you mean by "deploying on dev mode"?

Comment: Can you paste the code of your redux store?

Comment: No need. The problem was as you described. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure redux dev tools with redux-devtools-extension npm package.

```
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
export const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);
```

See section 1.3 in following link for more information.
https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension#12-advanced-store-setup

Another option

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(reducer, /* preloadedState, */ composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware)
));
```

Comment: This worked. I understand that the compose function would fail if the dev tools are not present. Is that all that was happening here?

Comment: As far as I know yes. When the extension is not installed, it is using Redux’ compose.
You can read more about this through following article by the developer of the library.
https://medium.com/@zalmoxis/improve-your-development-workflow-with-redux-devtools-extension-f0379227ff83

Comment: That seems suboptimal